# -webkit-line-clamp css not able to add in email template. How can add this property in email template?

Tags: html, css

-webkit-line-clamp css not able to add in email template. How can add this property in email template

I have made one video where i have added my needed property of css to inspect element then my desired result will be show then you can understand what i mean. Check this link for video [video](http://hippovideo.io/video/view/817690)

Comment: You can't...the propert is not supported by most (if any) email clients. Since it's an experimental property, I suggest you rethink the usage.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for overview on this my question.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you cannot have that functionality in an email.

Below are two sources with full lists and compatibility of email clients supporting **CSS**. 
I could not find `-webkit-line-clamp` or `line-clamp` anywhere.

Here you can see all valid **CSS** for **HTML** emails https://caniuse.email/

**EDITED:**

Also here https://elasticemail.com/supported-css/

**EDITED 2:**

Maybe you could achieve something like that using `overflow: hidden` together with a `gradient`. There is no reason that would not work;

```css
.text-truncate{
  width: 300px; 
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-truncate p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.text-truncate:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px; /* Extra 10px */
  height: 100px;
  width: inherit;
  background-image: linear-gradient( transparent 30%,  white 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="text-truncate">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed varius imperdiet dui, nec dictum ante viverra eget. Aenean lobortis bibendum mi eget pulvinar. Mauris eu turpis ipsum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris nec dolor tempor, aliquam est non, mollis augue. Fusce consequat enim arcu, vitae vulputate metus faucibus ac. Sed nec purus eget quam vulputate fringilla. Vestibulum nec metus est. Nam felis mauris, tincidunt vitae arcu non, vulputate luctus lacus. Pellentesque eget ultricies velit. Duis vehicula, velit eget maximus feugiat, lorem libero egestas turpis, eu ullamcorper nisl neque eget dolor.

Quisque quam orci, scelerisque mollis urna eu, suscipit tristique nunc. Phasellus sit amet sagittis mauris. Cras faucibus auctor quam, nec sollicitudin tellus volutpat id. In sed condimentum massa. Ut eleifend velit purus, et tincidunt dui ornare ac. Aenean finibus enim sit amet leo dignissim, sit amet egestas nibh iaculis. Nam sed lacinia diam, accumsan hendrerit tellus. Suspendisse maximus lobortis ligula quis finibus. Morbi eu libero in velit pellentesque convallis at bibendum lectus. Integer scelerisque, turpis sed sodales sagittis, dui augue cursus sem, ut bibendum tellus odio in leo.
</p>
</div>
<a href="#">Read More</a>
```

Comment: According your link, I have noticed that -webkit-line-clamp property is not present under the document. So Do you have any other solution in css which work like this property(-webkit-line-clamp)? So i can add that css to email content.

Comment: @BhavinThummar I think you cannot use this or any other property that does anything similar. 
I am sorry I didn't mention that in my answer.

Comment: Really thanks for your try. But My need is only for one line with condition  if line is fully showed in device then '...' (read more) not show after line. This three dot(...) is only show when line can not fully show with one line. I will show you that thing

Comment: I have made one video where i have added my needed property of css ti inspect element then my desired result will be show then you can understand what i mean. Check this link for video https://www.hippovideo.io/video/view/817690